# In R, I'm trying to assign entries as categorical variables but everytime I run one line code it overwrites and resets the other

Tags: r, statistics

```
credit$loan_grade_cat = with(credit, 1*(loan_grade == "A"))
credit$loan_grade_cat = with(credit, 2*(loan_grade == "B"))
credit$loan_grade_cat = with(credit, 3*(loan_grade == "C"))
credit$loan_grade_cat = with(credit, 4*(loan_grade == "D"))
```

This creates a new column called loan_grade_cat and works fine for loan_grade == "A" but not after that. For example, if I run the first line it will replace all A values with 1, but then I run the line for B and it only has 2 for all B values and zero for everything else.

[credit head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT3jz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing 4 lines of code, it can be changed with a single line

```
credit$loan_grade_cat <-  with(credit, as.integer(factor(loan_grade,
       levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), labels = 1:4)))
```